# How to convert chm files to one xhtml file

Tags: chm, xhtml

how do I convert CHM files int one xhtml file?

Comment: on what operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using Windows:

`1.` extract the HTML files from the CHM container from the command prompt with **HH.EXE**

example:

```
HH.EXE -decompile C:\Temp\decompile-folder C:\Temp\yourCHM.chm
```

`2.`  merge the HTML files into a single file (e.g. with [SoftSnow Merger](http://softsnow.griffin3.com/merger/merger.shtml))

`3.` convert the HTML file to XHTML (e.g. with [Simpletidy](http://download.cnet.com/Simpletidy/3000-10247_4-10506929.html))

or, if you don't mind spending $19.95, you can use **[ABC Amber CHM Converter](http://www.processtext.com/abcchm.html)**:

> reads CHM files and converts them to
>   PDF (doesn't require Adobe Acrobat to
>   be installed), HTML (single file and
>   web-site), RTF (MS Word doesn't need
>   to be installed), HLP, TXT (ANSI and
>   Unicode), DOC (MS Word), DBF, MDB (MS
>   Access), CSV, XML, XLS (MS Excel),
>   Clipboard

Comment: Keep in mind, HTML and XHTML ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML ) are 2 different things. Similar, but different.

Comment: It does't preserve original order of pages. It just merges HTMLs in alphabetic order of names of html files which is not necessarily how it structured logically.