# A better way how to view *.chm files

Tags: file-search, help-files

I'm able to decompile *.chm file using `hh -decompile <target_folder> <help_file.chm>` in `help_file.chm` location (see Question: [decompiling chm file: hh.exe requires only the filename. no full path is allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603637/decompiling-chm-file-hh-exe-requires-only-the-filename-no-full-path-is-allowed))

This gives folder with all pages from `*.chm` as single `*.html` files in single subfolder of `<target_folder>`. So I can use my favorite browser to view, but there is no user friendly search option availible.

Do you know better browser for viewing (and searching in) *.chm help files (or maybe JavaScript library which allows help me to search or build index for search trough decompiled files)?

### I'd like to:

- Be able to open topics/links in a new tabs ✔️
- Use mouse (rocker gestures) for navigation ✔️
- Search in topic names (`<H1>`)
- Fulltext search trough all files ✔️*

✔️ - This is possible in decompiled html files with my browser
✔️* - This is possible with with my filemanager, but it's slow and not so user friendly.

Thanks for your suggestions.

PS: According to this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/79358) is possible to merge all HTML files (26 000 in my case) into single file and then use browser fulltext search (or JS search limited to `h1` tag), but I'm a little bit scared by size of this page and its performance.